# How to check if a string contains accented Latin characters like é in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, non-ascii-characters

Given:

```
str1 = "é"   # Latin accent
str2 = "囧"  # Chinese character
str3 = "ジ"  # Japanese character
str4 = "e"   # English character
```

How to differentiate `str1` (Latin accent characters) from rest of the strings?

Update:

Given

```
str1 = "\xE9" # Latin accent é actually stored as \xE9 reading from a file
```

How would the answer be different?

Comment: I think you mean "\xE9" (double quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first strip out all plain ASCII characters with `gsub`, and then check with a regex to see if any Latin characters remain. This should detect the accented latin characters.

```
def latin_accented?(str)
  str.gsub(/\p{Ascii}/, "") =~ /\p{Latin}/
end

latin_accented?("é")  #=> 0 (truthy)
latin_accented?("囧") #=> nil (falsy)
latin_accented?("ジ") #=> nil (falsy)
latin_accented?("e")  #=> nil (falsy)
```

Comment: "é" actually stored as "\xE9" reading from a file. I've updated my question. Would you help in that case?

Comment: In that case the file is probably encoded in ISO-8859-1. Read the file and convert it to UTF-8 before doing the regex check. `IO.read("myfile", :encoding => "ISO-8859-1:UTF-8")`

Comment: What if that str="\xE9" is something I'm not able to change. How could that be recognized?

Comment: There is a probably a better way to do it, but this will detect "\xE9" in str: `str.force_encoding("binary").include?("\xE9".force_encoding("binary"))`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `/\p{Latin}/.match(strX)` or `/\p{Latin}&&[^a-zA-Z]/` (if you want to detect only special Latin characters).

By the way, "e" (str4) is also a Latin character.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a two-stage approach:

1. Rule out strings containing non-Latin characters by attempting to encode the string as Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1).
2. Test for accented characters with a regular expression.

Example:

```
def is_accented_latin?(test_string)
  test_string.encode("ISO-8859-1")   # just to see if it raises an exception

  test_string.match(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýþÿ]/)
rescue Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
  false
end
```

I strongly suggest you select for yourself the accented characters you're attempting to screen for, rather than just copying what I've written; I certainly may have missed some. Also note that this will always return `false` for strings containing non-Latin characters, even if the string also contains a Latin character with an accent.